# How can I find global minima on 2 multivariable function?

Tags: calculus

> "Try to find global minima of the function $y = 50 + x_1^2 + x_2^2 − 20(\text{cos}2\pi _1 + \text{cos}2\pi x_2)$ for
>   the interval $−5 \leq  x_1 \leq 5$ and $−5 \leq  x_2 \leq 5$"

This is my artificial intelligent homework I will calculate these question with simple hill climbing algorithm I know how to write a code but I dont math. I know how to solve simple variable version but unfortunately I don't know how to solve this problem can you help me for this problem. (I found nearly same question on this site but in that question there isn't an interval)

Answer (score 0):

Like the single-variable problem, it reduces to a search of critical points. The maximum and minimum will be among these.

First, in the interior, we have a critical point if the derivative is zero - that is, both partial derivatives are zero.
Second, on the edges, we have a critical point if the derivative in the tangential direction is zero ($\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}$ along the edges $x_1=a$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}$ along the edges $x_2=b$). The technique of Lagrange multipliers can also be used for this part, and would be necessary if the edges were curved.
Finally, any corners (the four vertices of the rectangular domain in this case) are always critical points.

Now, the catch? There are a lot of these points. Because of the rapid oscillation of those cosine terms, we get hundreds of critical points, most of which we can't even write down a closed form for.

All is not lost, though. For one thing, there's lots of symmetry; the function is even in both variables, and symmetric under exchanging them. That cuts the search down by a factor of $8$. For another - we're looking for the minimum. What happens if we just try to minimize each term? Oh, wait - we can do it for all of them in the same place. That place is, of course, the overall minimum.

Answer (score 0):

I think we have $$f(x_1,x_2)\geq 10$$ the equal sign holds if $$x_1=x_2=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that min$\{-20(cos2\pi x_1+cos2\pi x_2)\}=-40$, and that holds at least when $(x_1,x_2)=(0,0)$. Further, min$(x_1^2+x_2^2=0$, and that too holds when $(x_1,x_2)=(0,0)$. So, min $(y)=50+0-40=10$.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the objective function and then many answers can be obtained.

[image]

The global minimum being at $x = y = 0$ with a value of $10$